# I get this error "can't decompress data; zlib not available" when installing AWS EB CLI on MacOS 10.15

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, zsh, zlib

I am trying to install AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI (https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup) but am having the the greatest trouble understanding why it doesn't work (I'm not good with this kind of stuff so it might be something easy..)

I've followed all the setup instructions but I get the following output and error when I run this command `./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/bundled_installer`:

```
==============================================
I. Installing Python                          
==============================================

*************************************************************
1. Determining whether pyenv is already installed and in PATH
*************************************************************
    - pyenv was not found in PATH.

*********************************************************
2. Determining whether pyenv should be cloned from GitHub
*********************************************************
    - pyenv git repository already cloned to /Users/apple/.pyenv-repository. Won't attempt to clone again.

*******************************************
3. Temporarily export necessary pyenv paths
*******************************************

****************************************************************************
4. Checking whether Python can be downloaded (through curl, wget, or aria2c)
****************************************************************************

************************************************************
5. Installing Python 3.7.2. This step may take a few minutes
************************************************************
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.7.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/Python-3.7.2.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.2...
python-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.2 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/t9/6kkmnhns6g9192p5r2zwmf640000gn/T/python-build.20200204155232.99457
Results logged to /var/folders/t9/6kkmnhns6g9192p5r2zwmf640000gn/T/python-build.20200204155232.99457.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/private/var/folders/t9/6kkmnhns6g9192p5r2zwmf640000gn/T/python-build.20200204155232.99457/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/private/var/folders/t9/6kkmnhns6g9192p5r2zwmf640000gn/T/python-build.20200204155232.99457/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 204, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/private/var/folders/t9/6kkmnhns6g9192p5r2zwmf640000gn/T/python-build.20200204155232.99457/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 117, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/private/var/folders/t9/6kkmnhns6g9192p5r2zwmf640000gn/T/python-build.20200204155232.99457/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip._internal
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
make: *** [install] Error 1
   Exiting due to failure
```

I have the following in my `.zshrc` file:

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include"
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib"
CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include"
```

So I have no idea what is going on...

The only thing that could explain this is the following message I get when installing zlib with brew:

```
==> Caveats
zlib is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
```

But then when go to `/usr/local/opt` in can see `zlib` as a symlink so I don't understand..

```
$ ll /usr/local/opt/
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 apple  admin    28B Feb  4 14:43 openssl -> ../Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d
lrwxr-xr-x  1 apple  admin    28B Feb  4 14:43 openssl@1.1 -> ../Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d
lrwxr-xr-x  1 apple  admin    21B Feb  4 15:13 zlib -> ../Cellar/zlib/1.2.11
...
```

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291737/zipimport-zipimporterror-cant-decompress-data-zlib-not-available

Comment: @RodrigoM I'm on MacOS so I installed it with the following `brew install zlib openssl readline` so I don't think your link will help me (that's my bad, I didn't specify that I was on mac).

Comment: I could never get this to work on my Mac either, despite following the instructions in the Troubleshooting section. I had much better luck installing with `pip`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-advanced.html. Note that if you already have the aws cli installed, that there is a conflict between the two installations and you will have to downgrade aws cli: https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/issues/2

Comment: @littleforest thanks i'll try that

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing the [EB CLI via Homebrew](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-osx.html). This worked in my case whereas the other methods detailed [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup) did not.

Comment: Yes but I saw somewhere (in the issue section I think) that this was replacing that and that we shouldn't use the homebrew version anymore

Comment: Yes, well spotted. Under section [4.3 in "Frequently Asked Questions"](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup#43-on-macos-or-linux-systems-with-brew-is-this-better-than-brew-install-awsebcli) there is an answer regarding brew. However, the answer says only that their method is "better".

Comment: Pretty sure I saw something somewhere else  but yes I'll try this, if it solves my issue I don't really care after all. Will try it later on this week, thanks